# typescript recursive type exit condition

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

As far as I know, the recursion needs an exit condition or a base condition. I am using this `DeepReadonly` type during my program.

```js
type DeepReadonly<T> = {
  readonly [P in keyof T]: DeepReadonly<T[P]>;
};

type Teacher = {
    name: string;
    address: {
        street: string;
    }
};
type ReadOnlyTeacher = DeepReadonly<Teacher>; // works like a charm
type ReadOnlyString = DeepReadonly<string>; // still string
```

I cannot understand `DeepReadonly<string>` is `string`.

```js
type DeepReadonly<T> = {
  readonly [P in keyof T]: DeepReadonly<T[P]>;
};
// T is type string
type DeepReadonlyString = {
  readonly [P in keyof string]: DeepReadonly<string[P]>
}
```

I searched the [doc](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#more-recursive-type-aliases), but I haven't found any mentions about this behavior

Comment: Apologies, what is the question you're asking here?

Comment: @MingweiSamuel I have edited the question to be more concrete

Answer (score 0):

`DeepReadonly<string>` is string because readonly can only be applied to array literals and properties of an object. Same reason why `Readonly<string>` is `string` or why `readonly string` is invalid syntax.

```
'readonly' type modifier is only permitted on array and tuple literal types.
```

The literal string is already readonly. You cannot modify its value.

```js
let a = 'a';
a = 'b';
```

Here the string `'a'` wasn't modified, instead a new string `'b'` was assigned to the variable `a`.

Javascript already allows you to make the value of a variable readonly though, with

```js
const str = 'value';
```